# Jboss: initialize database with data

Tags: java, database, jpa, jboss

Since I haven't received an answer to my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24454486/problems-with-using-a-stateful-session-bean-from-a-singleton-bean). I've decided to try and find a different solution.

So, I've got a Java EE application that is deployed on a JBoss server and I'm asking if there's a way to initialize a database with some data, before the user starts interacting with the application. Apparently, a singleton bean that is executed at start-up is a problem (see my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24454486/problems-with-using-a-stateful-session-bean-from-a-singleton-bean))

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why the code from your other question fails, but you could try a couple of things:

- Assuming you use maven, you could create a unit test to populate your database using JPA. The downside is that when you build with maven the test will always be executed (unless you specify -DskipTests)
- Another thing you could try is using the ServletContextListener interface.

---

```
@WebListener
public class MyAppServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        // Initialize database here or create your 
            // own event for application startup and fire it
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        // Do nothing here
        }
}
```

Edit:

- 3rd approach: you could use liquibase (http://www.liquibase.org/). Then have something like this: http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/insert.html

Comment: I used the approach with context listener and it worked. The problem with the singleton bean that was executed at start-up was that apparently you can't execute methods on a stateful bean from a multithreaded environment and somehow a singleton bean is considered a multithreaded environment.

Comment: Please, consider posting it as answer to your other question for the community.